# Out of Memory Error when switching to Fragment with images loaded from UIL

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview, universal-image-loader

I have a FragmentActivity which is my menu that switches between fragments. The code used to switch between fragments is below:

```
public void changeFragment(Fragment targetFragment){
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_fragment, targetFragment, "fragment")
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out, android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
```

Each fragment contains a list view which has a custom adapter that displays images loaded using Universal Image Loader on each list row. It seems as though the images are not getting cleared from memory when switching between fragments. I eventually get the Out of Memory error after switching between fragments several times.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

More details from console:
E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 1448188-byte allocation.
I/dalvikvm﹕ "uil-pool-2-thread-2" prio=4 tid=16 RUNNABLE

UIL config:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
                //.threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
                .threadPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY + 3)
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
                .diskCacheSize(150 * 1024 * 1024) // 150 Mb
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
                .threadPoolSize(3)
                //.writeDebugLogs() // Remove for release app
                .build();
        // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

UIL Options:

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.section_load)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.section_load)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.section_load)
                //.cacheInMemory(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .build();
```

Comment: your fragments seem to be still in memory that might be why your images are still in memory

Comment: I'm changing to Home fragment for example like this changeFragment(new HomeFragment()); Would this leak?

Comment: Please, post you UIL configuration and list item's layout.

Comment: Updated with UIL config and options. What do you mean by list items layout?